Conditional probability of flower color
Task description: The BLUE flower color stems from a recessive allele, which we denote with b. Assume now that the parental generation both are heterozygous for that recessive allele (Bb). One of the offspring flowers shows a "normal" white color. Calculate the probability that this flower is also a "carrier" of the BLUE flower allele.
My reasoning:
So we have $b$ for blue color (recessive) and $B$ for white color (dominant). Both parental flowers have the $Bb$ genotype, meaning the distribution of their offspring will be: $\frac{1}{4} BB$ (white color phenotype), $\frac{2}{4} Bb$ (white color phenotype), $\frac{1}{4} bb$ (blue color phenotype). I apply the Bayes Rule to this problem:
$P(carrier|white) = \frac{P(white|carrier)P(carrier)}{P(white)} = \frac{\frac{2}{4} \cdot (\frac{2}{4} + \frac{1}{4})}{\frac{1}{4} + \frac{2}{4}} = \frac{0.375}{0.75} = 0.5 = P(Bb)$
However, in my brain, if I logically restrict that the offspring can only be of genotype BB or Bb (white color), there is a new distribution: $\frac{1}{3} BB, \frac{2}{3}Bb$, and we have a new "denominator" so to say:
$P(carrier|white) = P(Bb) = \frac{2}{3} = 0.66$
I am confused which way is the right one to think in this example, so if someone could help I'd be very grateful!
Some terminology:
-Allele: Variation of gene (e.g. if gene is "flower color", possible alleles would be blue, white,...)
-Recessive: Does not influence the appearance of a species
-Dominant: Masks the recessive allele aka determines the appearance
-Heterozygous: The two alleles for a gene (e.g. flower color) are not equal, i.e. Bb (homozygous would be BB)
-Carrier: Individual has recessive allele (b)

The Bayes formula is correct. The terms $P(\text{White}) = P(BB) + P(Bb) = 3/4$ and $P(\text{Carrier}) = P(bb) + P(Bb) = 3/4$ are correct.
However, the term $P(\text{White}|\text{Carrier})$ is incorrect.
Note the following:

$bb$ is Blue and a Carrier
$Bb$ is White and a Carrier
$BB$ is White and not a Carrier

Therefore,
$$ P(\text{White}|\text{Carrier}) = \frac {P(Bb)} {P(bb) + P(Bb)} = \frac {2} {3} $$
Plug in this will give you the result.
In fact, the conditional probability $ P(\text{White}|\text{Carrier})$ may be less intuitive and less convenient for calculation. If you consider
$$ P(\text{Carrier}|\text{White}) 
= \frac {P(\text{White and a Carrier})} {P(\text{White}) }$$
and you can see $P(\text{White and a Carrier}) = P(Bb) = 1/2$ more directly.
